# Cant get rid of condensation inside keezer

Tags: keg, kegerator, diy

I'm running a 5 cubic feet Magic Chef keezer with 2x6s for a collar so I can get an additional keg on the ledge. I cut the corners at 45 degrees and sealed off the collar with caulk, weather stripping, etc etc. I have two recirculation fans and a bag of Damp Rid and within 2 hours of starting it up there's condensation pooling in the bottom corner. I have the temp set to 37 degrees F. Any tips or anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of taps you are using and how they are mounted?

Comment: Could there be anywhere else warm, moist air is getting in?  I generally just don't worry about it, but my keezer lives outside.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use picnic taps? Every time the lid is opened, warm humid air is allowed to enter, cool, and result in condensation on surfaces. If this is the case, the standard mounted shank & faucet type taps should reduce the amount of times that the lid is opened and thus, reduce condensation.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer